# MySQL tables and JSON parsing . Foreign keys or not?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, parsing

I am reaching MySQL database from Android with PHP script and I am parsing returned values with JSON. It is working correctly. My problem is about MySQL.

I have two tables named `country` and `geography` and their structure are below.

**countries** table has these columns:

```
country_id* | country_name  and 20 more column...
```

**geography** table has these columns:

```
geography_id* | location   and 15-20 more column...
```

**(*) indicates primary key**

```
<?php

 //some connection properties here....

// PHP variable to store the result of the PHP function 'mysql_connect()' which establishes the PHP & MySQL connection  
 $db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
 mysql_select_db($db_name);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries, geography WHERE country_id = '". $_POST["COUNTRY_ID"]."'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  $output[]=$row;
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();   
?>
```

After run this script returning unwanted values. Assume that, when I request `country_id = 1` JSON is returning all rows of `geography` table. I want to retrieve only `geography_id=1`'s row. Must I use foreign keys to solve my problem. Or another way?

Comment: WHERE country_id = '...' AND geography_id=1

Comment: I tried your solution. But JSON only returning first row.

Comment: What is the link between the 2 tables ?

Comment: There is no link I only use country_id = x AND geography_id= x and it is working but now JSON only returning first element of table. When I request country_id = 15 for example it is not shown

Comment: Aside from there being no coded like between the tables, is there an association? i.e. What decides the country and geography?

Comment: So why are you querying for these two tables at same time ?

Comment: I mean no foreign key relation between tables. Logical association; geography table contains country's geographic information such as rivers, mountains, coordinates etc.

Comment: Okay, I think I have an answer for you. One sec

Comment: The answer I posted is the "cleanest" way - but it could also be solved by running two separate queries. Any reason why you are opposed to foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be adding a foreign key to (probably) your `geography` table by adding the column `country_id` (or something similar):

That column would contain the id of the country it references in the `countries` table. Then your query would look something like this:

```
"SELECT *
FROM `geography`
INNER JOIN `countries` on geography.country_id = countries.country_id
WHERE geography.country_id = {$_POST["COUNTRY_ID"]}";
```

For more information on joins, check here - this is one of the best articles I have ever read: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/